# How to prove that a sequence is unbounded

Tags: calculus

I want to ask, how to start a proof that shows a sequence to be unbounded

Define a sequence $\{X_n\}$ by

$$X_1 = 1 ,\quad X_{n+1} = X_n + \sqrt{X_n}  \quad \text{for}\ n \geq 1$$

Prove that $\{X_n\}$ is unbounded.

Comment: "We will show that for every $B$ there is an $n$ such that $a_n\gt B$."

Comment: assume that sequence is bounded and try to get contradiction.

Comment: Hint: prove by induction that $X_n \geq 1$. Hence $X_{n+1} \geq X_n + 1$, hence $X_n \geq n$, so...

Answer (score 2):

First,
$x_{n+1} > x_n \ge 1$
for all $n$.

Second,
$x_{n+1} \ge x_n+1
$.

Therefore,
$x_n \ge n$,
so $x_n$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

This is a comment
about the growth of
$x_n$.
My guess is that
$x_n \approx n^2/4 + cn$
for some $c$.

If we replace
$x_n$ by $f(n)$
and
$x_{n+1}-x_n$
by $f'(x)$,
this becomes
$f'(x) = f^{1/2}(x)$.
Playing around,
this has
$f(x) = x^2/4$
as a solution.

This suggests that
$x_n \sim n^2/4$.

Further playing around
suggests looking at
$y_n=x_n-n^2/4$.
Its equation is
$y_{n+1}+(n+1)^2/4
=y_n+n^2/4+\sqrt{y_n+n^2/4}
$
or

$\begin{array}\\
y_{n+1}
&=y_n-n/2-1/4+(n/2)\sqrt{1+4y_n/n^2}\\
&\approx y_n-n/2-1/4+(n/2)(1+2y_n/n^2)\\
&=y_n-1/4+y_n/n\\
\end{array}
$

Ignoring the $1/4$,
$y_{n+1}
\approx y_n(1+1/n)
$
or
$y_n \approx cn$.

Therefore,
it looks like
$x_n
\approx n^2/4+cn$.

I have to leave now,
so I'll leave it at this.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=\infty$, which implies that the sequence is unbounded.  In other words, one shows that:
$$\text{For any $M>0$, there exists $N>0$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $|a_n|>M$}$$
In this case, what you want to note is that $X_1 =1$, and $\sqrt{x}\geq 1$ for any $x\geq 1$.  With $X_{n+1} := X_{n+1} + \sqrt{X_{n}}$, prove that $X_n \geq n$ for all $n$, and conclude that $X_n$ is unbounded.

Comment: That's not the definition of unbounded; that's the definition of $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|=\infty$. The sequence $(a_n)_0^\infty=(0,1,0,2,0,3,0,\dots)$ is unbounded but it doesn't satisfy your definition.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the correction.